# Mongo DB $or query in PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, find

I can't figure out for the life of my to select from a collection with the `or` parameter. It's not working at all for me and I can't really find any documentation on it for php.

Here is my example code that doesn't return anything even though they exist in the collection:

```
$cursor = $products->find(
    array(
        '$or' => array(
            "brand" => "anti-clothes",
            "allSizes" => "small"
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: There are these concepts called *capitalization* and *apostrophes*... I'm wondering why so many seem to forget/ignore them when asking questions... `:P`

Answer (score 52, accepted):

```
The $or operator lets you use boolean or in a query.
You give $or an array of expressions, any of which can satisfy the query.
```

You provided only one element in the array. Use:

```
find(array('$or' => array(
  array("brand" => "anti-clothes"),
  array("allSizes" => "small")
)));
```

Comment: @Andrew - You should mark answers as correct by clicking the checkmark next to the answer.

Comment: yeah, it said i had to wait 4 minutes to accept the answer for some reason

Comment: @Karoly Horvath: Thanks, could you please add any reference to related docs?

Comment: @john: google.com. honestly, I don't even know what else do you want to know. all the information is needed is already here.

Comment: Well, if you google, this comes up first. Does this mean you're the docs now?

Comment: @blockhead: to me, the manual comes up first (both for "mongodb or" and "mongodb or query")