# Mongo DB find() with PHP using $and

Tags: php, mongodb

I've got this query In Mongo and it works fine:

```
db.getCollection('Users').find( { $and: [ { estatus: 1.0 }, { username: "administrador1" } ] } );
```

I'm trying to do the same call with PHP but I can't make it work, this is my PHP code:

```
$users = DB::connection(env('DB_DATABASE'))->collection('Users');
$test = $users->find(array('$and' => array(
    array("username" => "administrador1"),
    array("estatus" => 1.0)
)));
```

This gives me the following error:

**"Can't canonicalize query: BadValue unknown operator: $and"**

I saw this question with $or operator and thought it would be helpful but still couldn't make it work:
[Mongo DB $or query in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7451684/mongo-db-or-query-in-php)

This code does work properly in my PHP, its brings me all of the users:

```
$users = DB::connection(env('DB_DATABASE'))->collection('Users')->get();
```

How can i run my query through Mongo in PHP using find() and the $and operator?