# MongoDB query from PHP using `$and` and `$or` conditional filters

Tags: php, mongodb

Can I use the `$and` and `$or` conditional filters with PHP and MongoDB?

I am trying a simple `$or` to match where 1 field might have a few values (2 in the sample below):

```
$filter  = [
     '$or' => [
          ['compRounds.roundState' => 'open'],
          ['compRounds.roundState' => 'completed']
     ]
];
$options = ['sort' => ['compStartDate' => 1]];

$cursor = $collection->find($filter, $options);
```

But this doesn't return any documents to the `$cursor`.

This works if I remove the `$or` and only have 1 matching field, as:

```
$filter = ['compRounds.roundState' => 'open'];
```

The document structure would be like this:

[image]

Comment: Here is some info about using _and_ and `$in`respectively using MongoDB PhP driver: [findMany](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/current/tutorial/crud/#find-many-documents), [Usage of $in](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.find.php). Note that you can use `$in` instead of `$or` in your case.

Comment: please share your document example

Comment: @prasad_ is that older syntax? I have tried it with `$filter = array(
   'compRounds.roundState' => array(
    '$or' => array(
     'open',
     'completed'
    )
   )
  );`. Now get `Fatal Error` message at `/usr/bin/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Operation/Find.php on line 337`

Comment: Here is another example: [Mongo DB $or query in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7451684/mongo-db-or-query-in-php/7451709)

Comment: following the current published PHP Library (https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/v1.1/reference/method/MongoDBCollection-find/), they use a different square bracket structure. Are these threads, from many years ago, still relevant? as there was a big update to the library, from what reading I stumble across

Comment: For $in operator you can use this:

$filter = [ 'compRounds.roundState' => [ '$in' => ['open', 'completed'] ] ];

Comment: In any case your code is correct.
Please try with this $filter  = [ '$or' => [ ['compRounds.roundState' => 'open'] ] ]; and share result

Comment: @andranikasl, thanks - the syntax in your first comment has worked. interesting it is using an 'in' construct, rather than an 'or'. is this because it is referencing the same field, and an 'or' would be used if they were different fields?